# Have evolutionary biologists ever done anything like this?

Tags: evolution

1. Pick a protein that you claim evolved.
2. List the mutations that you claim happened during the evolution of the protein.
3. Pick one of these mutations.
4. Prove that it could happen in nature and produce a viable organism.

This seems like a way to test evolution.

Comment: Try looking at the long term E coli experiment, they have even show predictable and more importantly experimentally repeatable evolution. http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0014184

Comment: incorrect they showed evolution quite clearly. I also reccomend the research on evolution in response to changes in the  the thermal environment http://myxo.css.msu.edu/PublicationSearchResults.php?group=ve or the ones on antibiotic resistance http://myxo.css.msu.edu/PublicationSearchResults.php?group=ar

Comment: No they showed a change in protein expression quite clearly, if you are looking for a change in the protein structure I suggest the work on nylonase. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17512009 including it induced occurrence in a different bacterium, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7646041

Comment: If you think the sudden emergence of a new protein from nothing is predicted by evolution you don't understand evolution, nylonase is a different protein sequence with different structure and function, produced through a known mutation in the DNA sequence of a different protein. I honestly don't know what you are asking for at this point.

Comment: @John this "lad" obviously doesn't know anything about biology, but also doesn't want to learn (at least he doesn't show the humility typical of a real apprentice).

Comment: I have accused you of nothing. I am trying to ascertain what you are asking for. Now however that you have deleted your responses that prompted the statements shows you are only interested in an argument and not information. you have been given an example that fits your exact criteria as stated. so either change your criteria to reflect what you are actually asking for or indicate why you think it does not fulfill your criteria or we can only conclude you don't actually want an answer.

Comment: How exactly do you believe new proteins evolve? ALL proteins are changes in existing sequences.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about biology but a statement of a debating position. As usual with such trolls the final argument is completely vague.

Comment: @David AliceD and Chris, I disagree with the off-topic conclusions (and the down votes btw).  I believe this person framed a good question (although showing research would have helped) and deserves a chance for people to answer.  Saying it's "Off-topic" when _clearly_ it's not is not a good response.

Comment: @RunzWitScissors — I think the way you can distinguish an on-topic and an off-topic troll question is to ask whether or not the poster really is asking for an answer to a biological question. In this case the answer is no. What the poster is doing is really saying "I think such and such is the key test of evolution and nobody has done it therefore …" If this were a discussion group he could/would have come straight out and said this. Because this is a Question/Answer group he is resorting to this subterfuge. He is abusing this group and we should not tolerate his behaviour.

Comment: @RunzWitScissors I have to agree with David. You should have seen all the comments he wrote and later removed. Some are still here, so you can have an idea of the situation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, actually LOTS of proteins have already been sequenced in many different organisms, and the more related phylogenetically those organisms are, the more similar the corresponding proteins. You may go to the [National Center for Biotechnology Information](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) and see for yourself. Or you can work in a lab and sequence some proteins yourself, or just ask to see how people in such labs work.

Even more, we already know some proteins evolve fast, other slowly. Even more, some parts of proteins evolve faster than other parts, and that's related with the function that each part does.

But really, do you think biological evolution still needs to be "tested"? What about Newtonian physics? What about Einsteinian physics? What about the Periodic Table of Elements? Is it because of religion that you accept most physics and chemistry of the last 150 years, but not the main biology from the same period?

So you want an example?

Here is the insulin from *Pan troglodytes* (common chimpanzee):

```
malwmrllpl lvllalwgpd pasafvnqhl cgshlvealy lvcgergffy tpktrreaed lqvgqvelgg gpgagslqpl alegslqkrg iveqcctsic slyqlenycn
```

Here is the insulin from *Homo sapiens* (humans):

```
malwmrllpl lallalwgpd paaafvnqhl cgshlvealy lvcgergffy tpktrreaed lqvgqvelgg gpgagslqpl alegslqkrg iveqcctsic slyqlenycn
```

As you can see, they're very similar, except for a few letters (each letter represents a single aminoacid).

Now let's take a more distant animal, let's say, a pig (*Sus scrofa*):

```
malwtrllpl lallalwapa paqafvnqhl cgshlvealy lvcgergffy tpkarreaen pqagavelgg glgglqalal egppqkrgiv eqcctsicsl yqlenycn
```

Can you see there are more differences now?

The [National Center for Biotechnology Information](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) is free for you to research any protein you like, from any organism you like. As I said, there are probably millions, maybe billions, of proteins already sequenced. You can find out which aminoacids became different in the course of evolution, but you cannot come back in time to sequence the animals that lived millions of years ago. But one thing you can do is to search Google for "evidences of evolution" or buy books about basic Evolutionary Biology. I can suggest some if you want.

Comment: What's pathetic is your desire to prove evolution wrong, certainly because of religious bias. I may assume you are following the Abrahamic god, because only their followers are so eager to disbelieve biological evolution.

Comment: Evolution could be a mythology, like any science, like any religion. The difference is that the evidences are so overwhelming, that you need to close your eyes to them, so you won't lose your faith in a single old book.

Comment: Why don't you go to study the subject you pretend to be willing to understand?

Comment: Yeah, maybe evolution is wrong. Maybe a god and a goddess together created everything in a way that we believe evolution took place. OK, I can live with that.

Comment: Evolution is obviously wrong because it doesn't work even in basic tests like this question.

Comment: You should first study biology, learn the difference between apomorphies and plesiomorphies, understand how cladistics works, see how hierarchical are the phylogenetic groupings, among other things, before coming here with all your "certainty". Funny how you religious people never worry about physics and chemistry...

Answer (score 3):

nylonase.

nylonase is a different protein sequence with different structure and function from its parent protein. It does something the parent protein could not do. It is produced through a known mutation in the DNA sequence of the parent protein.
ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17512009

this capability shift through mutation has even been induced in other bacterium with similar starting proteins. ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7646041

A review of all three sequence studies can be found here. ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11092619

Comment: What do you mean by new mutation? It binds and digests a molecules that did not exist until 1935. To answer your first question yes. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11092619

Comment: my previous statement does, in addition I have added a reference in my answer.

Comment: no they actually can't, the parent protein cannot digest 6-aminohexanoate-oligomer, the substrate in question. Simply increasing the amount of present will do nothing. the Ell' sequence is different than the parent sequence. .

Comment: you believe an inactive protein sequence existed to digest a molecule that was invented in 1935? And if you want more information you could look at the papers' references, which identify the separate parent enzymes in detail. Or you could just read more than the abstracts since the parent proteins are identified.

Comment: Then you are not reading the papers, at least not past the abstracts, and since you seem unwilling to even bother reading the sources given you I suspect you are not actually interested in an answer. Since comments are not for discussion and you can't articulate a reason the sources given are insufficient, I will leave you here.

Comment: "Plus its not even on a gene. Its a plasmid. So its like saying tossing your breakfast around in your stomach is evolution" ________           now have evidence you don't even know what you are asking for. I suggest you take a few biology classes so you know something about genetics and proteins before you ask the question. I also suggest you look up what a plasmid is.

Comment: Its an independent set of DNA in the host. So whatever evolution happens on the plasmid is only those changes which the host has already adapted to. In other words not evolution at all.

Comment: t makes no sense, a mutation in a gene on a plasmid is the same is a mutation in any other DNA loop. It shows you don't understand bacteria genetics. If you wish to continue this, Isuggest you create a discussion thread.